# Closing and Restarting the Session Multiple Times within the same PHP Script

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-state

Would you please take a look at the code below. Is there a way, how to close and restart session multiple times in the middle of the php script?

The reason I am doing it is that I have another script that reads the current session variables, and gets the information about file download progress.

However, with the script below I get issues with headers. Thank you in advance.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['DownloadProgress'] = 0;
$_SESSION['ConnectionAborted'] = 0;
$_SESSION[`Downloaded`] = 0;
$_SESSION['FileSize'] = 0;
$_SESSION['KilobytesPerSec'] = 0;
session_write_close();



$filename = 'E:\DOWNLOAD\upload_test.txt';

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filename).'"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));


$handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');

while($chunk = fread($handle, 1024*64))
{

    echo $chunk;
    flush();

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['DownloadProgress'] += 1024;
    session_write_close();
    usleep(100000);
}

fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Wait, what are you trying to do here? This will most likely lock up the session file for most of the time; it would be better to write this information in a separate file and read that.

Comment: @Jack, hi and thanks for your response. My goal is to export file download progress information, which could be then read by the browser and used as needed. Say, that I export the information into a file, would not I have problems implementing such a solution for different OS' and different file systems? If you would have an example, that would help.